# Stitching together multiple videos without gap

Tags: java, php, video

Our client wants us to create larger videos from UGC videos specifically submitted to the client. So, I am looking for either a server side approach or a client side approach where

- Users will upload their video to any well-known video sharing site (YouTube/Vimeo etc) and give us permission to stitch it together.
- We can either make one video by combining it together server side (download, manipulate, upload)
- Or create a page with all the videos and fashion their playing in such a way that there is no gap.

The key operating concern is that there should be no gap while playing these videos. The effect should be one of [Jump Cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_cut). We are mostly a PHP shop, but PHP/Java solutions should be fine with us.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

http://www.flvsoft.com/bind_flv/

Comment: That is somewhat close to what we are looking for - but it seems like a desktop product - running on Windows. We are looking for a Server product potentially possible to integrate using an API or something we can install on Linux setup.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for format / size / basic editing stuff before - you just run the CLI tool from PHP. (you don't really want to be handling video streams natively in PHP).

Comment: That would work, but do you know of any video sharing site that allows me to download a video in one of the formats supported by ffmpeg?