# Is there a way to programmatically add captions to a Youtube video using their API?

Tags: upload, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to add a caption to a video when I upload it to youtube. The caption would say something like "Brought to you by Company ABC".

The way Google has described it [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions.html) seems very long winded and complex. Additionally, there is no link to usage with the Java API.

Does anyone know a simple way of doing this?

Thanks,
  Gearoid.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for might be more properly called an "annotation" (or in this case ["premercial"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=premercial)) than a "caption".

(A caption would be an appropriate term if someone was actually speaking "Brought to you by Company ABC", and you wanted people to be able to know that with no sound...either because they had the sound off, or were scanning the video programmatically, or because they are hearing-impaired.)

There is apparently no programmatic API at this point in time for using YouTube's native annotation features:

[Annotating YouTube videos programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175/annotating-youtube-videos-programmatically)

If you wanted to prepend a title card of some kind to your video (like it's your space to inject an advertisement) you can read around for approaches to do that operation before the upload:

[Stitching together multiple videos without gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048290/stitching-together-multiple-videos-without-gap)

You'd have a lot more options for making that intro sequence look spiffy, then.